# Angular 5 - Headers not being sent

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-services

I've this...

```
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import { ReqLogin, ResLogin, ResList, ResEmpty} from 
 '../../interfaces/general';
 import { GlobalService} from '../global/global.service';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';


 ...


list(): Observable<ResList> {
const url = this.gs.backendServer + this.gs.backend.endpoints.list;
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': this.gs.token
  })
};
console.log(httpOptions);
console.log(this.gs.token);
return this.http.get(url, httpOptions)
  .map(res => <ResList> res)
  .do(dataReceived => console.log(dataReceived));
}
```

the result of console:

```
HttpHeaders
headers:
Map(1)
size:(...)
:Map
[[Entries]]:Array(1)0:
{"authorization" => Array(1)}
key:
"authorization"
value:["wWTq3NP5LzynzTzYEcHUWgzBC5ioJ1DVW6WDR3QgIDAnc9yrDuVR92iyOQVgooGQ"]
length:1

wWTq3NP5LzynzTzYEcHUWgzBC5ioJ1DVW6WDR3QgIDAnc9yrDuVR92iyOQVgooGQ
```

So, the authorisation is really going inside options as expected.

But when I see the request...the headers is not there...

```
OPTIONS /list HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4600
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8
```

The question is: What's wrong ?

**Edit: The code is not wrong. I just figure out it's was the backend server trying to handle authorization on OPTIONS request**

Comment: Do you need to include the work *bearer* in front of the token when you send it? I know I normally do when I send a authorization token to an API.

Comment: You show `OPTIONS` request headers, which suggest you are using Cross Origin request. OPTIONS request takes place before the "real" GET request. If GET does not follow, maybe CORS policy is blocking the GET (which should have your desired header set).

Comment: Yes, @RadosławRoszkowiak ! That's was the problem...the backend was with issues. trying to handle authorizartion . it's was fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side when you are doing the **CORS** you need to add the following for the header options for the "preflight" to your existing **CORS*

```
if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.sendStatus(200);
} else {
    next();
}
```

I had the same issue with options and wasted pretty much a day on this, now I won't forget it.

Answer (score 1):

```
let header = new HttpHeaders();
    header = header.append('Authorization', this.gs.token);

const httpOptions ={ headers:header};
```

can you try changing the way the headers are created

Comment: No lucky :( But I really appreciate !

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `HttpHeaders` instead of passing object:

```
list(): Observable<ResList> {
  const url = this.gs.backendServer + this.gs.backend.endpoints.list;
  let httpOptions = new HttpHeaders()
                         .set('Authorization', this.gs.token);

  return this.http.get(url, { headers: httpOptions })
    .map(res => <ResList> res)
    .do(dataReceived => console.log(dataReceived));
}
```

Comment: No lucky :( same result